# Method to reliably determine abnormal statistical values

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm searching for a statistical method to determine if a player is cheating in an online game.

Given a number  of positive points and a number of negative points per player (score) and given $n$ players ($n <= 64$). Each player can cheat independent of each other. I used standard deviation, which works great on a single player but fails miserably as soon as several players are cheating at the same time.

Is there any useful algorithm or formula for this problem?

Comment: I've posted it to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/method-to-reliably-determine-abnormal-statistical-values, with further explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Your question needs some more information:

How is their score generated (what kind of game is it)? What should your non-cheating data look like? 
How do people cheat? How will their score be different (in a statistical sense) when they are not cheating?
Do you know roughly the proportion that are cheating? Or is that something you also want to find out?

I would also look at outlier detection algorithms: wikipedia looks useful on this topic ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Identifying_outliers)). Using a [Q-Q plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Q_plot) on your data may also be useful if your non-cheating data should be approximately Normally distributed; points that are significantly above the line might be cheaters.

You may also try posting this on the stats.stackexchange.com since this is really more of a statistics question.